# JS: How to create a file of type image, from base64

Tags: javascript, blob, png, multipartform-data, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert `png` file, produced by https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to a blob file, that I'd send to API.

Code below produces such output that API does not throw 400, however the file is somehow corrupted.

Is there something wrong with the way I construct the blob?

```
  const data = new FormData();
  const [, binary] = image.toDataURL().split(',');
  const blobFile = new Blob([window.atob(binary)], { type: 'image/png' });
  data.append('attachments[]', blobFile, 'screenshot.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out canvas is already well equipped for translating itself to blob. All you have to do is use `canvas.toBlob(cb)` and you are ready to go.